# How bind data from multiple datasource field in a single gridcontrol cell

Tags: wpf, devexpress

I'm a beginner with WPF. I need to show two textblock in a single gridcontrol cell and bind them to a different fields from data source. The first step is clear for me. But I can't understand how I should bind Text property of TextBlock to datasource properies.
Please, give me some notes and advices.

Below some code (xaml) lines. So I need to show in the first TextBlock property ProjectPriority and in the second - ProjectDeadLine.

That's my datasource

```
<dx:LinqCollectionViewDataSource x:Key="LinqCollectionViewDataSource" Culture="ru" ContextType="{x:Type ORM:FPMDataContext}" CollectionViewType="{x:Type ListCollectionView}" dx:DesignDataManager.DesignData="{dx:DesignDataSettings RowCount=5, UseDistinctValues=True}" Path="ActualProjectView">
    <dx:LinqCollectionViewDataSource.SortDescriptions>
        <ComponentModel:SortDescription Direction="Ascending" PropertyName="ProjectDeadlineDate"/>
        <ComponentModel:SortDescription Direction="Descending" PropertyName="ProjectPriority"/>
        <ComponentModel:SortDescription Direction="Descending" PropertyName="ProjectCreationDate"/>
    </dx:LinqCollectionViewDataSource.SortDescriptions>
</dx:LinqCollectionViewDataSource>
```

And that's GridControl:

```
<dxg:GridControl AutoPopulateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Data, Source={StaticResource LinqCollectionViewDataSource}}" Margin="0,-10,0,10">
        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="ProjectPriority" >
                <dxg:GridColumn.DisplayTemplate>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProjectPriority}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProjectDeadLine}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </dxg:GridColumn.DisplayTemplate>
            </dxg:GridColumn>
        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView ShowTotalSummary="True" ShowAutoFilterRow="True" FocusedViewChanged="TableView_FocusedViewChanged"/>
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
    </dxg:GridControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a ItemsControl like a `GridControl` your `Itemssource` is a `Collection` of Type `T`. Inside your Column you can access the Properties of class `T` via Binding.

It seems you have a Collection called `Data`. The Framework will look for the `ProjectPriority` Property in each Entry of this List.

Comment: Yes you are right. As a ItemSource I use LinqCollectionViewDataSource from DX where ContextType="{x:Type ORM:FPMDataContext}" CollectionViewType="{x:Type ListCollectionView}" and ORM:FPMDataContext is LinqToSql class. But it doesn't work... =(